# How can i install phpmyadmin to a virtual server?

Tags: mysql, unix, phpmyadmin

I have a virtual unix server and currently i have to go through an awkward web interface thats not very easy to use. Basically i would like to be using phpmyadmin, but i don't know how to install it. As all i have to manipulate the server is a primitive control panel.

So how do i install to a virtual unix server?

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure if this should be here or in serverfault so sorry if i got it wrong).

Comment: copy the files, that's it. btw most servers have builtin phpmyadmin, you just have to find it on the control panel.

Comment: What is the web interface called that you're using?  Is there a section that allows you to SSH into the virtual server?

Comment: its just called control panel theres no sign of an actual product name, its got an option called mysqladministrator which is poor to be frank.

Comment: @Jai you do have FTP access ? right, if not how do you upload your website files ?

Comment: yes i have ftp, but i don't know what top upload to get phpmyadmin? ahh just seen your edit. ill give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this question is more suited for serverfault, but anyways here is a solution.

Download the latest archive from phpmyadmin.net

And follow the instructions at - http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#quick_install

Just to clarify the point raised by Ek0nomik, even if you dont have shell access:

You can upload the extracted files from the phpmyadmin archive to the server via FTP.

**update**
Here is a short step by step you can do.

1. Download the latest phpmyadmin archive to your computer and extract it to a folder.
2. rename the file  `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php`
3. Edit the file and change the line `$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';`  to add a value for this so you can use cookie authentication, something like this (use any random value of your own):

   `$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'gcaietr6snbct';`
4. Upload the folder via FTP to a folder on your server accessible via web.

If your website forder is `/home/.../public_html` upload the folder say `phpmyadmin` to which you extracted the contents of the phpmyadmin archive to this `public_html` folder.

Now you can access it as `www.yourwebsite.com/phpmyadmin`

Comment: This didn't answer the OP's question.  He is looking for information on how to install it with his virtual server, meaning he doesn't have a command line or window environment to work with.  All he has is a web interface provided by his hosting provider.

Comment: @Ek0nomik you can always upload files via FTP. If you cant do that then you cant even upload your wabsite. SO the downvote is completely unjustified.

Comment: after i have uploaded it, how do i then access it?\

Comment: @Jai where did you upload the folder. For starting I would suggest upload to a subfolder in your already functioning website. See me edit for more info